# Why not working the RedTube API with ordering?

Tags: api

I'm sorry, I speak a little English.

I would like use the RedTube API, but I found a bug. Can you help me?

If search (A) is missing or search= (B) is empty, ordering will not work. If there is search=test, it works the ordering (C).

Today: 2021-04-17 14:45 UTC

(A) https://api.redtube.com/?data=redtube.Videos.searchVideos&output=json&ordering=newest&period=alltime

(B) https://api.redtube.com/?data=redtube.Videos.searchVideos&output=json&ordering=newest&period=alltime&search=

```
{"videos":[
{"video":{"video_id":"31519261","publish_date":"2020-05-12 18:37:41" ...
{"video":{"video_id":"33251331","publish_date":"2020-06-26 21:38:46" ...
{"video":{"video_id":"21961231","publish_date":"2019-09-19 09:20:38" ...
"count":95515}
```

(C) https://api.redtube.com/?data=redtube.Videos.searchVideos&output=json&ordering=newest&period=alltime&search=test

```
{"videos":[
{"video":{"video_id":"39439771","publish_date":"2021-04-16 15:20:48" ...
{"video":{"video_id":"39415341","publish_date":"2021-04-12 15:35:18" ...
{"video":{"video_id":"39400721","publish_date":"2021-04-10 15:05:45" ...
"count":268}
```

Please help how to use this API.